# How to remove this warning from wordnik sample for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am using an example from WordNik samples-sdk, I killed most memory leaks but there's a warning that I can't understand what it is and how to fix it!

I have asked help on their Google group but while they answered to pretty much to every question that I asked, they keep ignoring this one, I am hopeful that the collective brain of stackoverflow solves the problem.

This file generates a warning on iPad/iPhone - [file](https://github.com/wordnik/api-examples/blob/master/src/objectivec/main/wordnik/BaseWordnikService.m) where the warning is generated.

```
Wordnik/WordService.m: In function '-[WordService fetchDefinitions:useCanonical:]':
Wordnik/WordService.m:52: warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct Word *', expected 'struct Definition *'
```

The whole sdk-sample is [here](https://github.com/wordnik/api-examples/tree/master/src/objectivec/main/wordnik/).

Comment: If you can, use clang to compile and see if it generates the warning. It'll tell you then what warning flag produced the warning. But in general a warning like this means the compiler doesn't know how to convert the types.

Comment: I can give it a shot - the code works it doesn't crash or anything though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to link to [this file](https://github.com/wordnik/api-examples/blob/master/src/objectivec/main/wordnik/WordService.m). On line 52 we find this:

```
Definition * def = [[Definition alloc]init:dict];
```

The compiler can't work out whether the `init:` method refers to `(Word *)init:` from the Word class or `(Definition *)init:` from the Definition class. It's incorrectly guessing that it's the method from the Word class and therefore giving you a warning that you're initialising a Definition* variable with a Word* object.

It's solvable with a cast like so:

```
Definition * def = [((Definition *)[Definition alloc]) init:dict];
```

Or even:

```
Definition * def = (Definition *) [[Definition alloc]init:dict];
```

And no, the compiler isn't smart enough to realise that `[Definition alloc]` probably returns a Definition object.

(I can't help but mention that whoever wrote that sample code has a very casual attitude to releasing/autoreleasing objects and an apparent love of memory leaks. In that one file `word` is never releaed, none of the values stored in `def` are ever released and nor is `definitions`)

Comment: if there was a way to hit 3 not one checkmark on this answer I would made a request to double that up. You answered to my question AND you put in very simple words the core issue of that "sample"....

Comment: Just figured out why you have to do this.  Normally this isn't an issue in ObjC code, and that's because the -init method is declared to return an id.  In the sample code, Word and Definition both have -init methods that are declared to return object references of their particular types.  As grahmparks said, this causes the compiler to get confused as to which -init method is being called, and it gives the warning.  Normally, -init would return an id, which can be assigned to any object pointer variable.  The real fix here is to change those -init methods to return id.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is just that, sample code, not intended for real-world use. But Wordnik (for which I work) is working on an official Objective-C SDK. It fully supports the Wordnik API, and has some nice features like request batching. If you're interested in early access, there's information in this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/wordnik-api/browse_thread/thread/13bcfb6b53c7eaee

Comment: I haven't questioned the quality or purpose of the sample, I am asking help to get the sample fixed since your company is refusing to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but try adding the following statement near the other #import statements in WordService.m:

```
#import "Definition.h"
```

Comment: the share the same hunch - I tried that, it doesn't fix the problem. :-)